# ObjectInputStream Overwrites all data

Tags: java, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

It seems objectoutputstreams can be full of booby-traps. Currently, I believe that my outputstream is working correctly, but when I try to read in from the file, all the data is overwritten for the hashmap I am using. 
Most of the time the int for the hashmap value is not 0 but when I retrieve the object from file, the hashmap has every key value to be 0.

Here is the pseudo/real code for my problem.

Writing :

```
HashMap<State, int> temp= new HashMap <state, int>();

    try{
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new   FileOutputStream("/Users/_____/Documents/hash.ser");
             ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
             out.reset(); //added before and after for testing.

             //iterating through hash to see if everything is correct before outputting. (and it is)
             Set set = hash.entrySet();
             // Get an iterator
             Iterator i = set.iterator();
             // Display elements
             while(i.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
                temp.put((state)me.getKey(), (int)me.getValue());

                //output is as expected
                System.out.println("Serializing "+me.getValue() + "\n\n\n");

           }


             //using flush and reset hoping for effect.
             //tried using write(temp)
             out.writeUnshared(temp);
             out.flush();
             out.reset();
             out.close();

             fileOut.close();

          }catch(IOException i){
              i.printStackTrace();
          }
```

Input(After much debugging the error appears to be here).

```
 try
          {
             FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("/Users/_____/Documents/hash.ser");
             ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);


         HashMap<state, int> temp= new HashMap <state, int>();

         //hash = (HashMap) in.readObject();

         temp=(HashMap) in.readObject();
         Set set = temp.entrySet();
         // Get an iterator
         Iterator i = set.iterator();
         // Display elements
         while(i.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
            hash.put((state)me.getKey(), (int)me.getValue());

            //Always is 0.
            System.out.println("Getting IN "+me.getValue() + "\n\n\n");

       }



         in.close();
         fileIn.close();
      }catch(IOException i)
      {
         i.printStackTrace();
         return;
      }catch(ClassNotFoundException c)
      {
         System.out.println("class not found");
         c.printStackTrace();
         return;
      }
```

Comment: So ... what is your actual question?  It would help if you provided an MVCE that we could run for ourselves.

Comment: Is there anything immediate I might be missing as to why an InputStream (or possibly the OutputStream) is changing all of the key values?

Comment: Can't say.  If I / we could run the code ourselves, we might have a better handle on what the symptoms are, and from that work back to the cause of the problem is.  Right now, the most plausible explanation is that the entries weren't really there in the first place.

Comment: Another possibility is that you have declared fields of your `State` class to be `transient` ... or implemented custom serialization methods incorrectly.

Comment: How do I make sure they are not transient? I never used that keyword. I'm decently confident in my .equals/hashCode() but if that's all it could be I'll continue looking at that.

Comment: Waiting for an MVCE ........................

Comment: What is a MVCE? Also I believe I got it working. I'm not sure why but I added "implements Serializable" to all of the parent classes and that seems to have fixed it. Just wondering, does the child as well as its parent need to implement serializable??

Comment: Yes. All parents &  childs have to implement Serializable unless they are transient

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If the problem was fixed by adding `Serializable`, then you must have been squashing an exception somewhere.  Serializing a class that does not inherit `Serializable` (or `Externalizable`) will result in an exception.

Comment: *"Just wondering, does the child **as well as** its parent need to implement serializable?"* - No.